# How to use a jQuery variable in CSS property

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I having the following jQuery which finds the height of a responsive image:

```
        $(document).ready( function() { //Fires when DOM is loaded
            getImageSizes();
            $(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
                getImageSizes();
            });
        });
        function getImageSizes() {
            $("#slideshow img").each(function() {
                var $height = $(this);
                console.log( $height.height() );

            });

        }
```

And my goal is to use the $height variable to specify the height of a div with the ID of slideshow.

I assume I can use this:

```
$('#slideshow').css({'height': $height + 'px;'});
```

However it is not working (no height is specified).

I included the above line like so:

```
        $(document).ready( function() { //Fires when DOM is loaded
            getImageSizes();
            $(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
                getImageSizes();
            });
        });
        function getImageSizes() {
            $("#slideshow img").each(function() {
                var $height = $(this);
                console.log( $height.height() );

                $('#slideshow').css({'height': $height + 'px;'});
            });

        }
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can we see this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: You do understand that the `height` of `#slideshow` is going to be height of the last image. So if the last image in `$("#slideshow img")` height is 10 then that is what your `#slideshow` height is going to be.

Comment: I'm not sure yet.  The good news is that each image is the same height, so I was thinking about first finding the height of the responsive image, and then adding a constant that looks good in all viewports or, adding an extra percentage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are logging `$height.height()`, but then only using `$height` in the CSS.

If you named your variables better, it would be easier :p

```
var $height = $(this).height();
$("#slideshow").css({"height":$height+"px"});
```

Or my preference:

```
document.getElementById('slideshow').style.height = this.height+"px";
```

Comment: any reason for js version preference, other than performance ? :O

Comment: I think performance is a good enough reason. I may not have been around in the days where 8Kb was a lot of memory, but you wouldn't know it from my obsession with efficiency!

Comment: Yes, it is. I was just curious and was thinking if I can learn something new :)

Comment: Okay, I got this to work.  I am sorry, I found the code from a previous stack overflow question.  I am very, very new to jQuery!  It seems my function is not getting a height on page load, only on resize.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`$height` is a jQuery variable. You need to get the height of it by calling `.height()`.

```
$('#slideshow').css({'height': $height.height() + 'px'});
```

Or, you could store the actual height as a variable instead.

```
var height = $(this).height();
$('#slideshow').css({'height': height  + 'px'});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It seems the function getImageSizes(); is not being fired correctly on page load. But it does work correctly on resize now.  The console reports a value of 0 on page load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the jQuery object `$(this)` for your variable `$height`

Make it: `var $height = $(this).height();` and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It seems the function getImageSizes(); is not being fired correctly on page load. But it does work correctly on resize now.  The console reports a value of 0 on page load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your event handler:

```
        function() {
            var $height = $(this);
            console.log( $height.height() );

            $('#slideshow').css({'height': $height + 'px;'});
        }
```

You're attempting to do `$height` (which is a jQuery object) concatenated with `'px;'` (a string). This ends up with the string `'[object Object]px;'`, which obviously isn't what you want. You need to use the value of the height instead. This is I think what you want:

```
        function() {
            var height = $(this).height();
            console.log( height );

            $('#slideshow').css({'height': height + 'px'});
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It seems the function getImageSizes(); is not being fired correctly on page load. But it does work correctly on resize now.  The console reports a value of 0 on page load. Any ideas?